# Minimizing Type I and Type II errors Simultaneously

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to understand why I can't simultaneously minimize Type I error and Type II error simultaneously. A non-randomized Hypothesis test is essentially a deterministic partition of the Range space of our Random Variable.

$$R_0=\{x\in R: Reject Null\}\hspace{4mm}R_1=\{x\in R: Accept Null\}$$

where $R_0\cup  R_1=R$

If  I  try to  minimize the event of a type I Error then I can essentially remove some $x$ from  $R_0$ to $R_1$ then have the new partition of $R$ as $R_0^{'}\cup  R_1^{'}=R$

if

$$P_{\theta_0}(x\in R_0)=\alpha$$
$$P_{\theta_a}(x\in R_1)=\beta$$

then the new rejection region, $R_0^{'}$ post-transferring of x  will have 
$$P_{\theta_0}(x\in R_0^{'})\leq\alpha$$
$$P_{\theta_a}(x\in R_1^{'})\geq\beta$$

Thus In attempting to reduce the event of Type I error I have increased the event of a Type II error. But I have read that this trade-off only holds in  fixed sample size why is that. Is an increase in sample size decrease both events simultaneously?

Comment: When the sample size has gone up to "the entire population", both error probabilities have become 0, so it's not unreasonable to hope that they might both decrease as sample size increases.

Comment: If you always reject, you will have no Type I errors.  If you always accept, you will have no Type II errors.  Of course, neither of those policies is useful, but it means whatever policy you adopt (if you don't have perfect information) will neither minimize the number of Type I errors nor the number of Type II errors.

Comment: The probabilities of type 1 and type 2 error vary in opposite directions. This can be seen from a diagram like in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/440673/119261) post. We can only minimize the error probabilities, not the error themselves. So you should say simultaneous minimization of *probabilities* of type 1 and type 2 errors is not possible. As for fixed sample size, you can compare this situation to sequential hypothesis testing where sample size is not fixed.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Did you mean If you always reject you will have no Type  II errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all hypothesis tests, we calculate a $p$-value based on a test statistic calculated from our sample. Usually, we determine a threshold (significance level) $\alpha$ such that if $p < \alpha$, we reject the null hypothesis $H_0$. Note that our $p$-value is calculated under the assumption that $H_0$ is true, and represents the probability of the given parameter (e.g. mean) of the sample being observed *given* $H_0$ is true, so 
$$P(\text{type I error}) = P(\text{reject }H_0 \text{ when } H_0 \text{ is true}) = \alpha$$
as we only reject $H_0$ when $p \leq \alpha$. The point to note here is that the probability of a type I error *only* depends on the significance level.

The probability of a type II error will depend on the population parameters and the sample size, since we make such an error when our observed sample fails to lie in what you have called $R_0$ - the $p$-values which will force us to reject $H_0$. In most hypothesis tests, the distribution of the test statistic calculated for a sample becomes more and more concentrated as we increase the sample size. For example, in hypothesis tests for the population mean, increasing the sample size decreases the standard deviation of the sample mean. Hence, the test is more sensitive to extreme values of the calculated test statistic and is more likely to give extreme $p$-values (upon which we would reject the null hypothesis). If you have a specific hypothesis testing procedure in mind, I would be happy to flesh out the details for that procedure for you.

The point to note here is that the probability of a type II does not only depend on the significance level, and in nearly all cases decreases with sample size. So one can simultaneously minimize the two errors by decreasing the significance level and increasing the sample size.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly. We set the probability of a type I error according to the significance value chosen. As sample size increases then our  null hypothesis becomes more concentrated around the null parameter therefore our rejection region becomes larger since the tails account for less probability  resulting in a smaller acceptance region therefore  reducing type  II error. Then we can reduce the significance level and increase sample size to reduce both errors. Is this correct

Comment: @NoeVidales Your characterization of a type II error has the right intuitive idea. As for type I errors, it's simply a consequence of how most hypothesis tests are structured that the probability of a type I error is the significance level chosen (we don't deliberately 'set' the probability of a type I error). But yes, the main take away is that the significance level can be reduced and the sample size can be increased to reduce both errors.